# mjpeg quality question

Tags: raspi-config

In the uv4l-raspicam.conf file is there a way to improve the mpeg quality?  I've adjusted the **quality** parameter from 70 to 100 but I can see no difference in the output.

Thank you
Jim

```
encoding = mjpeg
width = 1920
height = 1080
framerate = 5
#custom-sensor-config = 2

### dual camera options:
# stereoscopic-mode = side_by_side
# camera-number = 1
# decimate = yes
# swap-eyes = yes

### still and/or video options:
quality = 95
```

Comment: The quality setting you're already using is the only one available for setting mjpeg quality in that settings file. It's a little difficult to recommend alternate courses of action without some more information - is there a specific problem you're trying to correct?